# Get Upper tag value depending on low level attributes

Tags: xslt, parallel.foreach

I am pretty new to XSL and considering a problem transforming a xml file with XSL.
My xml looks like this:

```
  <studentlist>
    <student name="Peter">
    <sem name="5>
    <mod name="science"/>
    </sem>
    </student> 
    ...
    ...
    </studentlist>
```

There more students in this studentlist and I want to extract all names of students who, for example, study science so the output would like this:
Science: Peter, Will, Jeffrey

I am using one template matching "studentlist/student/sem/mod". 
I can extract every module using this matcher but the problems are:
1. Repetitive matches still get displayed which is I want to avoid 
2. I can't reach the student name from that point and even if, I have no clue how to create a list of my results.

I tried to solve this using an inner for-each, but either absolute paths nor relative paths seem to work out here.

Could anyone help me or give me a hint how to achieve this, actually easy problem, with XSL?

Edit: the structure of my xml isn't showed. I will edit it later on my computer.

Edit: I am using XSLT 2.0. The thing is, I have more modules, not only science (but the structure within the xml stays the same). E.g. there are politics, languages, etc. So what I want to do is to show all students in a list dependend on the module. The output I want would look like:
Science : Peter, Jeffrey, ...
Politics : Vivien, Sarah, Antonio, ...
Languages: Hans, Fiola, Béatrice, ...

I had earlier a similar result, but I changed too much and I can't reach the old version anymore. But I had something like:
Science: Peter
Science: Jeffrey
Politics: Vivien
Politics: Sarah

And this is what I meant by "repetitve". I couldn't afford to list all students behind the module.

This is my current XSL, not working though..

```
<xsl:template match="studentlist/student/sem/mod">
<xsl:for-each select="./name">
    <xsl:variable name="currName" select="name"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="studentlist/student/sem/mod@name">
        <xsl:if test="$currName = $name">
            <xsl:text>$currName = $name</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please post your XSLT and the expected output (as code). --  I am also puzzled what do you mean by  "repetitive matches" - does your list have multiple entries for the same student? -- Finally, state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated my starting post. Your result seems to be a good start. I hope my edited post clears things up.

Comment: So basically, you want to group the students by subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to extract all names of students who, for example, study
>   science so the output would like this: Science: Peter, Will, Jeffrey

Apparently, you want to group the students by subject - so why don't you do exactly that?

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/studentlist">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="student" group-by="sem/mod/@name">
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/@name" separator=", "/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This seems pretty good! What if students have more subjects? E.g Both Peter and Vivien study languages?

Comment: It should still work (I have removed the unnecessary assumption).